# How to remove spaces from many file names under Cygwin

Tags: batch-file, renaming

Im hoping that someone can help me, I need to remove spaces (not replace with underscores) from several thousand files on a system with cygwin.
Can I do this from the shell using rename or mv somehow?

Currently:

file one.mp3
file two.mp3

All files need to become:

fileone.mp3

filetwo.mp3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default Cygwin shell is bash, so...

Try this command line, replacing $DIR with the directory under which you want to perform said conversion, and check the output:

```
find $DIR -type f -name '* *' | while read f; do d="${f%/*}"; f="${f##*/}"; echo mv "$d/$f" "$d/${f// }"; done
```

If you are satisfied with the commands that would be executed, just remove the echo before mv and repeat to execute the actual renaming. Note that this will only rename files, but not directories.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer to change file name, here is the code to change directory names:

```
find $DIR -type d -name '* *' | while read f; do d="${f%/*}"; f="${f##*/}"; echo mv "$d/$f" "$d/${f// }"; done
```

The only difference is the fourth argument from the beginning of the line. The letter "f" is changed to "d", corresponding to file and directory respectively.